# changing an element in a second list at a certain index in python

Tags: python

Hi I have a problem with changing the element of the second list. This program is for making bowling score chart.

I have two lists

```
rollA = [10, 6, 8, 3, 10, 10, 6, 7, 8, 10]
rollB = [0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 10]
```

In the program, I add the two lists in the same index, for example, I add `10` with `0`, and `6` with `3` and `8` with `0` and so on. I want to make a program that changes the element of `rollB` into `/` when the element of the specific index of `rollA` is not `10`, but the added sum of `rollA` and `rollB` of the specific index is `10`. For example, if I add `8` and `2`, the added sum will be `10`, and I want to change the `2` into `/`.

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if rollA[i] != 10 and (rollA[i] + rollB[i] == 10):
        rollB[i] == "/"
```

This is the program I devised so far, but the elements of the second list won't change if I make the code like this. How should I fix this program to function properly?

Comment: The `==` (equality) operator tests for whether the elements are already equal; to *assign* a new value (assigning the value on the right to the value on the left) you need to use the `=` (assignment) operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `zip()` function we are iterating over `rollA` and `rollB`. Then if the conditions you mentioned - the sum of them are 10 and the element is not equal to 10, the element of the `rollB` is replaced with the `/`

```
rollA = [10, 6, 8, 3, 10, 10, 6, 7, 8, 10]
rollB = [0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 10]
for i, j in zip(rollA, rollB):
    if i + j == 10 and i < 10:
        rollB[rollB.index(j)] = '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is in `rollB[i] == "/"` it returns either `True` or `False` .The assignment symbol is `=`, not `==`. The later one checks for matches. Change your code to :

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if rollA[i] != 10 and (rollA[i] + rollB[i] == 10):
        rollB[i] = "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` is the equality check operator. In order to **assign** a value, you need to use the `=` operator:

```py
rollB[i] = "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a comprehension way:

```
rollA = [10, 6, 8, 3, 10, 10, 6, 7, 8, 10]
rollB = [0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 10]

rollB = ["/" if x + y == 10 and x < 10 else y for x,y in zip(rollA, rollB)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
rollA = [10, 6, 8, 3, 10, 10, 6, 7, 8, 10]
rollB = [0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 10]
new_list = []

for count, val in enumerate(rollB):
   if val + rollA[count] == 10:
       new_list.append('/')
   else:
       new_list.append(val + rollA[count])
```

By creating an `if` and `else` statement within your enumerated (indexed) `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

check your demands and then change `rollB[idx] = "/"`

```
def my_func(rollA, rollB):
        for idx, elem in enumerate(rollB):
            rollB[idx] = "/" if (elem + rollA[idx] == 10) \
            and (rollB[idx] > 0) else rollB[idx]
        return rollA, rollB
    
    my_func([10, 6, 8, 3, 10, 10, 6, 7, 8, 10], 
            [0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 10])
```